# Cross Domain Conversion Tracking Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set up my analytic account and wondering if anyone can help shed some light on what I may be doing wrong.  I have 6 e-com sites with products and the shopping cart is on a 7th separate site.  Each site has its own unique domain.

I have a property set for each domain and then one additional property that is set as a global account.  The theory was to track for each separate property and then additionally in the global account.  This might be overkill since I am not overly concerned with traffic on the individual sites.  But what I am having trouble with is I am paying for adwords so the ad lands on a shopping1.com and checks out on shopping7.com its not registering as a conersion since there is a switch in the domain name.

Here is the code that I, any input on how to make all 7 sites work as one and adwords realizing there was a conversion would be greatly appreciated.  Do I need to set the domanname element?  Also, do I need to add code to everything that links back and forth to each of the separate sites?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-site1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  _gaq.push(['global._setAccount', 'UA-global']);
  _gaq.push(['global._setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['global._trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is okay, but not sufficient. First yes, you should use _setDomainName (with the value set to the respective domain names shopping1.com, shopping2.com etc).

More importantly you need to attach the linker functions to links, forms and iframes (and redirects, although  with redirects you need to do the linking yourself) - basically every place where people change from one of your domains to another (it's not necessary to attach linker function to links that do not go to your domains).

Google Analytics uses cookies to store data, which cannot be shared between domains. The purpose of the linker function is to attach session information to the url so it is transmitted to the other domain, where it is read by the Google script and stored into a new cookie. [Take a look at the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains) to see how the _link and linkByPost-functions are used.

If you are doing redirects you need to be careful that the redirect keeps the Google parameters.

Linker functions result in very long and ugly urls. Cross domain tracking works much better with Universal Analytics where you only have to transmit a single parameter (the client id) between domains.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  I will go in and ad he link functions as suggested.  One question though, the domainname value, what is the difference between using the respective domain names vs using none.  I thought I would have to use none.  And if i set the global domain name if i am not using none, would i add the .com of the shopping site they are on or the .com of the global property which is the corporate site where the shopping cart is located.